# Linux Driver: how do I access PCI sound card ADC and DAC

Tags: linux, audio, drivers

recently I got interested in Linux Driver Development. I read LDD3 book, a number of articles and examples. So I decided that it is time to try something on my own.

So what IO aim for: **I want to find out how to read the ADC data from my PCI sound card and how to write data to the DAC**

I searched a lot for examples and they all end up using ALSA api from User Space. This is not what I want to do.

I want to create my own interface to the User Space, through which I will transfer the data and will configure the device.

So here are some questions:

1. Is this possible at all? Or I should stick to ALSA.
2. Some design guidelines will be very appreciated. (I have some idea how to do it but I need other opinions).
3. Where can I find some example code, tutorials, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See [Writing an ALSA driver](http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/writing-an-alsa-driver/), and the documentation of your hardware.